# SQL Server create clustered index on nvarchar column, enforce sorting

Tags: sql-server

I want have a small table with two columns `[Id] [bigint]` and `[Name] [nvarchar](63)`. The column is used for tags and it will contain all tags that exist.
I want to force an alphabetical sorting by the Name column so that a given tag is found more quickly.

Necessary points are:

1. The Id is my primary key, I use it e.g. for foreign keys.
2. The Name is unique as well.
3. I want to sort by Name alphabetically.
4. I need the SQL command for creating the constraints since I use scripts to create the table.

I know you can sort the table by using a clustered index, but I know that the table is not necessarily in that order.

My query looks like this but I don't understand how to create the clustered index on Name but still keep the Id as Primary Key:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
               WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Tags]') 
                 AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tags] 
    (
        [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        [Name]  [nvarchar](63) NOT NULL,

        CONSTRAINT AK_TagName UNIQUE(Name)
    )
END
```

**Edit:**

I decided to follow paparazzo's advice. So if you have the same problem make sure you read his answer as well.

Comment: Without explicit ORDER BY there is no such thing as ordered table. Period. Just think about parallel execution.

Comment: Tables have no order, never, and it doesn't matters. What matters is what you query for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify that the Primary Key is `NONCLUSTERED` when declaring it as a constraint, you can then declare the Unique Key as being the `CLUSTERED` index.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tags] (
    [Id]    [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]  [nvarchar](63) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Tag PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (Id ASC),
    CONSTRAINT AK_TagName UNIQUE CLUSTERED (Name ASC)
);
```

Also specifying `ASC` or `DESC` after the Column name (within the key/index declaration) sets the index sort order.  The default is usually ascending.

Comment: I think it would be best to read the following answer from dba stack exchange on when to use a nonclustered primary key https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7744/46361

Answer (score 3):

You should **NOT** do what you want to do.

Let the Id identity be the clustered PK.  It (under normal use) will not fragment.

A table has no natural order.  You have to `sort by` to get an order.   Yes data is typically presented in PK order but that is just a convenience the query optimizer may or may not use.

Just put a non clustered unique index on `Name` and sort by it in the `select`.

You really need bigint?  That is a massive table.

Comment: I always use bigint for the Id because int will get critical for other tables and I'm deriving from the same base entity (important for nhibernate).

If the user types in some letters like let's say "su" I want it instantly to show suggestions like "summer" or "sun". Do you really think non clustered is better for that?

Comment: Why in the world would you be deriving from this table. I stand by my answer take it or not.

Comment: Well I'm not so experienced in indices so I better will follow your advise and take non clustered. Thank you